# Interrupt scrolling transitions in D3.js

Tags: d3.js, scroll

I'm using the scrollama javascript library to write a "scrollytelling" article that involves transitioning D3 graphs in and out of view as the user scrolls. It is mostly working, but the graphs pile up on top of each other if I scroll too quickly.

[Here is a jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nancynancy/w8y1qs2d/) based on this [example by the scrollama author](https://russellgoldenberg.github.io/scrollama/sticky-side/). In my example, the colored dots should fade in one at a time. If you were to scroll quickly to the end, the intermittent dots should not show up. The following snippets show how I've set up the transitions:

I define some functions that create my "graphs", and then call them.

```
var makeCircle0 = function(){

  g.append("circle")
    .attr("cx", 50)
    .attr("cy", 100)
    .attr("r", 20)
    .attr("fill", "red")
    .attr("class", "redcircle")

  g.selectAll(".redcircle")
    .attr("opacity", 0)
}

makeCircle0();

// Do this for makeCircle1, 2, and 3, also.
```

Then, I make functions to handle the transitions. This one says to make the red circle fade in and put the other circles at 0 opacity. I do this for all the circles/stages.

```
var showCircle0 = function(){

  g.selectAll(".redcircle")
  .transition()
  .duration(1000)
  .attr("opacity", 1)

  g.selectAll(".yellowcircle").attr("opacity", 0)
  g.selectAll(".greencircle").attr("opacity", 0)
  g.selectAll(".bluecircle").attr("opacity", 0)

}
```

This section creates an array of my transition functions so that I can call them at specific steps in the page as you scroll. This is similar to how [Jim Vallandingham handled his scroller](https://vallandingham.me/scroller.html).

```
var activateFunctions = [];
activateFunctions[0] = showCircle0;
activateFunctions[1] = showCircle1;
activateFunctions[2] = showCircle2;
activateFunctions[3] = showCircle3;
```

Finally, this calls the desired function at the right step in the page. Which it does... but not without halting the other transitions that got triggered in a previous step, resulting in multiple dots showing up at various stages.

```
function handleStepEnter(response) {
  step.classed('is-active', function (d, i) {
    return i === response.index;
  })

  figure.call(activateFunctions[response.index])
}
```

How can I prevent this?

Comment: I think [this](https://jsfiddle.net/cgo9rfj4/) is what you are looking for (the transition doesn't quite line up with the segments on the left, but the circles match the numbers). Is this correct?

Comment: @AndrewReid this is great! So all you've done is "interrupt()" first before starting any new transitions?

Comment: Pretty much - interrupt() will cancel any transitions on a selection.

Comment: Okay interesting. If I have a several classes that might be transitioning (like the redcircle, yellowcircle, etc.) I would have to interrupt all of them?

Comment: If there is a risk that they are still transitioning - which is why I used class to select them all and id to select one individually.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you need to interrupt a transition, d3-transition has a method for that:

```
selection.interrupt();
```

This will cancel a transition on an selection. *If using named transitions you can specify a name by providing interrupt with one argument indicating the name of the transition to cancel.*

---

If this is a generic version of your function to show an element:

```
function show() {
  selectionToHide.attr("opacity",0);

  selectionToShow.transition()
     .attr("opacity",1);
}
```

Without using selection.interrupt you set the opacity to zero, and then the next tick of any transition in progress continues to update the opacity and finishes carrying out the transition. By adding interrupt we avoid that. Here's an updated [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cgo9rfj4/).

However, there is another solution - we can apply another transition on the elements that we want to not show. To do so we just replace the transition with a new one:

```
function show() {
  selectionToHide.transition()
     .attr("opacity",0);

  selectionToShow.transition()
     .attr("opacity",1);
}
```

This will replace existing unnamed transitions (as yours are not named) and fade out elements, rather than simply hiding them all at once. Here's a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/v9kowbg8/) of that. *Of course if you have many elements this can be refined as to only apply a transition on any elements that are transitioning (not those that are already hidden) to reduce the amount of active transitions.*

*I haven't touched the scrolling, the circle that is shown should have its index match the displayed number, but it seems the number doesn't always match the scroll position, but this is a separate issue*

Comment: This is great! Will this work if there is a delay() as part of the transition?

Comment: It should - a delay is part of a transition, if replacing or interrupting a transition, you'll remove the whole previous transition, including the delay.

Comment: I can demonstrate that delay won't affect anything - [here's](https://jsfiddle.net/snzp1eb4/) a fiddle showing both interrupt and replacing the transition with a new one. The initial transition modifies radius after a delay, but it never starts as it is cancelled/replaced.

Comment: @GerardoFurtado, thanks! Only appropriate it was  you for the 1000th - if I'm not mistaken I believe I gave you yours a bit over 2 years ago when I was still pretty fresh. Looking forward to being able to close as dupe - with usually less than 5 regulars in d3 it was generally wait to you came online and saw it.

Comment: Actually we have just 2 regular golden badge users! That's why it's good having another active golden badge holder.

Comment: @GerardoFurtado, I meant just regular d3 folks gold badge or otherwise, it has been hard to get to the threshold of five close votes on a dupe (or any other close reason for that matter) without gold support because of how few regulars there are. But with Alto getting gold any day now too, hopefully housekeeping will be a bit easier.