# Removing elements by class on scroll

Tags: javascript, d3.js

Note: I asked [this question about interrupting transitions during a scroll](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55600310/interrupt-scrolling-transitions-in-d3-js), but am trying a different technique now that is resulting in a similar issue that doesn't get resolved with the accepted (and working) answer.

This time, rather than initializing all the graphs with 0 opacity and having a separate function to change the opacity that gets called on each step, I'd like to use `selection.remove()` in each drawing function. I want to do this so that out-of-view graphs don't get in the way of any mouseover interactions that I might want on the current graph.

For example, I have functions that clear the existing graphs and then draw the current one with some transition:

```
var makeCircle0 = function() {
  d3.selectAll(".nancygraphs").interrupt().remove()
  g.append("circle")
    .attr("cx", 50)
    .attr("cy", 100)
    .attr("r", 20)
    .attr("fill", "red")
    .attr("id", "red")
    .attr("opacity", 0)
    .transition()
    .duration(1000)
    .attr("opacity", 1)
    .attr("class", "nancygraphs")
}
```

These functions are put in a list

```
var activateFunctions = [];
activateFunctions[0] = makeCircle0;
activateFunctions[1] = makeCircle1;
activateFunctions[2] = makeCircle2;
activateFunctions[3] = makeCircle3;
```

And depending on the step, the function gets called to draw the correct graph

```
function handleStepEnter(response) {
  console.log(response)
  step.classed('is-active', function(d, i) {
    return i === response.index;
  })

  figure.select('p').text(response.index);
  figure.call(activateFunctions[response.index]) // HERE!
}
```

[Here is a jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nancynancy/fk4ej9w2/59/) to illustrate. Basically, if you scroll back-and-forth quickly then old graphs don't get cleared and you'll notice several graphics in view simultaneously. Why isn't `d3.selectAll(".nancygraphs").interrupt().remove()` doing the job?

Answer (score -1):

Three observations regarding your approach:

First, according to the d3 manual on
[transitions](https://github.com/d3/d3/blob/master/API.md#transitions-d3-transition):

> `remove`: remove the selected elements when the transition ends.

The remove will not interrupt already running transitions - it only removes when all transitions have stopped. More specifically it seems to act when `__transition__.count` of an element reaches `0`. You could consider using a non-d3 remove implementation here, e. g. [jQuery](https://api.jquery.com/remove/).

Second, from the same manual:

> Interrupting a transition on an element has no effect on any transitions on any descendant elements. (...) you must therefore interrupt the descendants: `selection.selectAll("*")`

You should call interrupt on *both* by doing `d3.selectAll(".nancygraphs").interrupt().selectAll("*").interrupt()`.

Third, it is never a good idea to directly couple mouse or scroll input to your logic (when you directly couple input events to e. g. attaching a transition, you might be doing so many thousands of times): did you use a [debounce](https://lodash.com/docs/#debounce) function? The lodash implementation is highly recommended.

After trying these modifications I would assume your current problem is solved. If it is not, a further way of debugging would be to log / overwrite the `__transition__.count` attribute of your elements.